# How to use GetChildAtPoint with PointF

Tags: c#, winforms

Im trying to write a basic drawing app with some formulas that requires me to keep my points precise.
all is working well but one part that will allow me to proceed with this program.
I need to use the `Control.GetChildAtPoint` Method to see if there is an object at a certain point of the line but my points is all in `pointF` (`float`).
here is a short piece of the code that should make sense.

```
    if (poscount > 15) {
            //to see if point is close to an object
            if (this.GetChildAtPoint(point2) != null) {
                label1.Text = "I found an object";                                      
            } else label1.Text = " no object found";

        }
```

Sorry for the stupid example but at the `point2  (which is a`pointF`) it gives an error that I cant convert from a`float`to`System.Drawing.Point`.
I cant find a way to convert it and keep the accuracy.
Is there a way I can use`GetChildAtPoint`with a`float`?

Comment: `Control.GetChildAtPoint` takes a **Point**, not a Point**F**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument could be converted as follows.

```
if (poscount > 15)
{
    // to see if point is close to an object
    Point iPoint = new Point((int)point2.X, (int)point2.Y);
    if (this.GetChildAtPoint(iPoint) != null)
    {
        label1.Text = "I found an object";                                      
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Text = " no object found";
    }
}
```

Comment: Just throwing it out, but [Point.Truncate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.truncate.aspx), [Point.Ceiling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.ceiling.aspx), and [Point.Round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.round.aspx) can be used as well for convenience.

Comment: @Anthony Thanks for the comment, I wasn't aware of these conversion functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, will converting it to an int not loose accuracy?

Comment: Actually, I just thought of it and I don't really need the deep accuracy as I'm going to add a cushion to the point. so it will destroy the accuracy anyhow. thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Also, given that a `Control` keeps track of its location via a `Point` and not a `PointF`, being able to locate a child control via a `PointF` would never return a different child control than a method searching via just a `Point`.